# Applying conditions to dataframe based on columns specified in a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the sample df as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'weight':[10,20,30,40,50],
                'speed':[100,120,140,160,180],
                'distance':[1000,1100,1200,1300,1400],
                'cat':['Y','N','N','N','Y']})
```

And I am applying the conditions to my df based on the values given below in the following way.

```
speed_margin = 160
weight_margin = 20
distance_margin = 1300
catergory = 'N'

conditions = np.where((df['speed'] < speed_margin) & (df['cat'] == catergory)
                    & (df['weight'] > weight_margin) & (df['distance']<distance_margin))
df1 = df.loc[conditions]
```

However, the columns for the conditions are not always the same, and they are suuplied by the user in the form of a list. For example, if:

```
conditions_list = ['speed', 'distance', 'cat']
```

I need to automate the above `conditions` code to only include the columns that are supplied by the user in `conditions_list`. As in this case, since there are only 3 column names in the `conditions_list` (`weight` col is missing), the `conditions` must look like:

```
conditions = np.where((df['speed'] < speed_margin) & (df['cat'] == catergory)
                    & (df['distance']<distance_margin))
```

if `conditions_list` was:

```
conditions_list = ['speed']
```

Then, `conditions` must be:

```
conditions = np.where((df['speed'] < speed_margin))
```

How can I make sure the conditions are applied only to the columns that are supplied in the list by the user?

Comment: How do you chose the operator? (`>`/`==`/`<`)

Comment: They are fixed rules, they remain constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to define each condition as a lambda to be applied to some column, then use `pd.DataFrame.transform` for checking each condition, finally aggregating with `pd.DataFrame.all`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'weight':[10,20,30,40,50],
                'speed':[100,120,140,160,180],
                'distance':[1000,1100,1200,1300,1400],
                'cat':['Y','N','N','N','Y']})

speed_margin = 160
weight_margin = 20
distance_margin = 1300
catergory = 'N'

conditions_list = ['speed', 'distance', 'cat']

funcs = {
    "speed":    lambda x: x < speed_margin,
    "cat":      lambda x: x == catergory,
    "weight":   lambda x: x > weight_margin,
    "distance": lambda x: x < distance_margin,
}

conditions = df.transform({col: funcs[col] for col in conditions_list}).all(axis=1)

out = df.loc[conditions]
```

out:

```
   weight  speed  distance cat
1      20    120      1100   N
2      30    140      1200   N
```

PS: if you use `np.where`, which returns integer indices, safer would be to use `iloc` instead of `loc`; but even better would be to omit it entirely and use the boolean mask directly as above.

Answer (score 0):

Make a *condition mapping* which maps columns to the needed subqueries/conditions. That will allow a quick dataframe [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) on requested column list:

```
cond_map = {'speed': 'speed < 160',
            'weight': 'weight > 20',
            'distance': 'distance < 1300',
            'cat': 'cat == "N"'}

df_ = df.query(' and '.join(cond_map[c] for c in cond_list))
```

---

Case #1:

```
cond_list = ['speed', 'distance', 'cat']
df_ = df.query(' and '.join(cond_map[c] for c in cond_list))
print(df_)
```

---

```
   weight  speed  distance cat
1      20    120      1100   N
2      30    140      1200   N
```

---

Case #2:

```
cond_list = ['speed']
df_ = df.query(' and '.join(cond_map[c] for c in cond_list))
print(df_)
```

---

```
   weight  speed  distance cat
0      10    100      1000   Y
1      20    120      1100   N
2      30    140      1200   N
```